# ERROR: Unable to Preview JasperReports in Jaspersoft 6.5.1

Tags: eclipse, groovy, eclipse-plugin, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Currently I am working on a project with some older code in it. When trying to preview the JasperReports within JasperSoft Studio 6.5.1 I have run into a slew of errors. After working through a few of them, I seem to have hit a brick wall with this one (shown below this text). I have tried the following solutions:
- Switching the report to Java.which didn't work becuase most of the project is handled with groovy expressions.
- Switching the groovy jar from the default one given by JasperSoft to a newer version
- Setting the Jasper library to equal the version ex: Jaspersoft Studio 6.5.1 has the Jasper Library Jar 6.5.1

ERROR

> > java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of java/net/FactoryURLClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a
> >     different type with name "net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRField"
>
> at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:304)at
>   com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController.compileJasperDesign(ReportController.java:481)
>     at
>   com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController.access$8(ReportController.java:466)
>     at
>   com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController$1.run(ReportController.java:369)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader
>   (instance of java/net/FactoryURLClassLoader) previously initiated
>   loading for a different type with name
>   "net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRField" at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:814)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:362)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:265)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:1004)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:999)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getSuperClass(ClassNode.java:993)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.isDerivedFrom(ClassNode.java:936)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.castToNonPrimitiveIfNecessary(InvocationWriter.java:858)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OperandStack.doConvertAndCast(OperandStack.java:347)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OperandStack.doGroovyCast(OperandStack.java:282)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitCastExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:741)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.CastExpression.visit(CastExpression.java:87)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.prepareSiteAndReceiver(CallSiteWriter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.prepareSiteAndReceiver(CallSiteWriter.java:224)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.makeCallSite(CallSiteWriter.java:272)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCachedCall(InvocationWriter.java:307)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:392)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:104)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:459)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:767)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:66)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.makeCallSite(CallSiteWriter.java:303)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeNormalConstructorCall(InvocationWriter.java:563)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeConstructor(InvocationWriter.java:572)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitConstructorCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:818)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ConstructorCallExpression.visit(ConstructorCallExpression.java:46)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.BinaryExpressionHelper.evaluateEqual(BinaryExpressionHelper.java:316)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.BinaryExpressionHelper.eval(BinaryExpressionHelper.java:84)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBinaryExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:638)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.BinaryExpression.visit(BinaryExpression.java:51)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(StatementWriter.java:607)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:357)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitExpressionStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:620)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:42)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(StatementWriter.java:84)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:158)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:566)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:288)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(StatementWriter.java:84)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:158)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:566)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:104)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:115)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitStdMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:430)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitConstructorOrMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:387)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:126)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:507)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:53)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitClass(AsmClassGenerator.java:233)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$16.call(CompilationUnit.java:813)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1055)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:102)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:203)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:286)